# Definition of conjugate momentum for more than one independent variables

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the definition of the conjugate momentum of the function $f$ if the Lagrangian has more than one independent variable, such as:

$$L=L(t,x,f,f_x,\dot f, g,g_x,\dot g)$$

where $f=f(t,x)$, $g=g(t,x)$?

---

I know that for a one-independent variable case $$p_i={\partial L\over \partial\dot q_i}$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugate momenta are still defined by $ \pi_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$. For example, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization#Real_scalar_field.